# how do I extract the Url data from my string

Tags: python, string, extract

I have the following string which contains many Url values. How do I extract the Url after the DataUrl term in this string? So I get a list of Urls
for example: americanexpress.com, vice.com, chegg.com

{'DataUrl': 'americanexpress.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '96', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7350'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '600.2', 'PerUser': '3.6'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '362'}}, {'DataUrl': 'vice.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '97', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '15703.61'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '489.97', 'PerUser': '1.38'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '208'}}, {'DataUrl': 'chegg.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '98', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '6280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '882.3', 'PerUser': '6.2'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '402'}}, {'DataUrl': 'mlb.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '99', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '564.1', 'PerUser': '3.42'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '427'}}, {'DataUrl': 'xnxx.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '100', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '5560'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '1271', 'PerUser': '10.1'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '95'}

I have tried various FindAll expressions.

Comment: do you mean FindAll from BeautifulSoup or similar ? you have something similar to JSON data, not HTML.

Comment: are you missing last `}`... ?

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in package called json, which can be used to work with JSON data.

You can convert your python object to a json object and then get DataUrl easily.

Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: I have tried the following: test = open(r'data.txt', 'r')
test = test.read()
test = json.dumps(test)
test = json.loads(test)          how would i get the DataUrl values?

Comment: After excecuting test = json.loads(test), test has the full JSON object. Now you can use a for loop to get DataUrl from each entries.

Comment: @hthomas if you can load it with `json.loads()` then see code in my answer - I made one of examples with `json.loads`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like part of `JSON` data so if you have complet `JSON` data then you could use module `json` to load it and search `DataUrl` in dictionary.

If you have incomplet JSON data then you can use `regex`

```
text = '''{'DataUrl': 'americanexpress.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '96', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7350'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '600.2', 'PerUser': '3.6'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '362'}}, {'DataUrl': 'vice.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '97', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '15703.61'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '489.97', 'PerUser': '1.38'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '208'}}, {'DataUrl': 'chegg.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '98', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '6280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '882.3', 'PerUser': '6.2'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '402'}}, {'DataUrl': 'mlb.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '99', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '564.1', 'PerUser': '3.42'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '427'}}, {'DataUrl': 'xnxx.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '100', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '5560'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '1271', 'PerUser': '10.1'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '95'}'''

import re

urls = re.findall("'DataUrl': '([^']*)'", text)

print(urls)
```

Result

```
['americanexpress.com', 'vice.com', 'chegg.com', 'mlb.com', 'xnxx.com']
```

---

You can also try to do it with `.split("{'DataUrl': '")` and `split("',")`

```
text = '''{'DataUrl': 'americanexpress.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '96', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7350'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '600.2', 'PerUser': '3.6'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '362'}}, {'DataUrl': 'vice.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '97', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '15703.61'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '489.97', 'PerUser': '1.38'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '208'}}, {'DataUrl': 'chegg.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '98', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '6280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '882.3', 'PerUser': '6.2'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '402'}}, {'DataUrl': 'mlb.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '99', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '564.1', 'PerUser': '3.42'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '427'}}, {'DataUrl': 'xnxx.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '100', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '5560'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '1271', 'PerUser': '10.1'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '95'}'''

urls = text.split("{'DataUrl': '")
urls = [item.split("',")[0] for item in urls if item]
print(urls)
```

Result

```
['americanexpress.com', 'vice.com', 'chegg.com', 'mlb.com', 'xnxx.com']
```

---

if you had complete and correctly formatted JSON - with `"` instead of `'` - then you could use module `json`

Here I use complete JSON

```
text = '''[{'DataUrl': 'americanexpress.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '96', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7350'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '600.2', 'PerUser': '3.6'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '362'}}, {'DataUrl': 'vice.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '97', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '15703.61'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '489.97', 'PerUser': '1.38'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '208'}}, {'DataUrl': 'chegg.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '98', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '6280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '882.3', 'PerUser': '6.2'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '402'}}, {'DataUrl': 'mlb.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '99', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '7280'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '564.1', 'PerUser': '3.42'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '427'}}, {'DataUrl': 'xnxx.com', 'Country': {'Rank': '100', 'Reach': {'PerMillion': '5560'}, 'PageViews': {'PerMillion': '1271', 'PerUser': '10.1'}}, 'Global': {'Rank': '95'}}]'''
text = text.replace("'", '"')

import json

data = json.loads(text)
urls = [item['DataUrl'] for item in data]

print(urls)
```

Result

```
['americanexpress.com', 'vice.com', 'chegg.com', 'mlb.com', 'xnxx.com']
```